# name or attribute error - constantly having to use globals and even then it doesn't always work

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to make a UI for this countdown timer, I keep running into the problem with python not seeing that variables are defined outside of whatever function I am making. I tried using globals but this sometimes doesn't work either. Is there anyway of getting functions to recognize that I have set the variables outside of the functions.

btw: even if I get the below code to stop the function errors, it might not work because I haven't got past the function attribute errors.

example errors:

> NameError: name 'times' is not defined
>
> NameError: name 'hr' is not defined
>
> NameError: name 'hours' is not defined

```
import time
from tkinter import *
global hours
global minutes
global secs
global loop
global counter

loop = 0

def timerstart():
    global loop
    global hours
    global minutes
    global secs
    hours = int(timer.entry1.get())
    minutes = int(timer.entry2.get())
    secs = int(timer.entry3.get())
    loop = 1


counter = hours*3600+minutes*60+secs



while loop == 1:
    while counter > 0:
        global counter
        counter-=1
        hr, sc = divmod(counter, 3600)
        mn, sc = divmod(sc, 60)
        mins=int(counter/60)
        hr=int(mins/60)
        time.sleep(1)

timer = Tk()
timer.entry1 = Entry(timer)
timer.entry2 = Entry(timer)
timer.entry3 = Entry(timer)
timer.clock = Label(timer, text='%d hours, %d minutes and %d seconds' % (hr, mn, sc))
timer.hours = Label(timer, text='Hours: ')
timer.mins = Label(timer, text='Minutes: ')
timer.secs = Label(timer, text='Seconds: ')
timer.start = Button(timer, text='Start', command=timerstart)


timer.clock.grid(row=0, column=0)
timer.hours.grid(row=1, column=0)
timer.entry1.grid(row=2, column=0)
timer.mins.grid(row=3, column=0)
timer.entry2.grid(row=4, column=0)
timer.secs.grid(row=5, column=0)
timer.entry3.grid(row=6, column=0)
timer.start.grid(row=7, column=0)
timer.mainloop()
```

Comment: It think your indentation is quite off..

Comment: It is, I copied it over wrong. I am trying to fix the question right now.

Comment: Actually, copy paste your exact code. One of us can help you format it. It would be easier that way.

Comment: I just did. Thats what I am using atm.

Comment: You will get the Nameerror `hr isn't defined` because you haven't set it to anything at all, the computer gets to the while loops and doesn't know what 'hr' is.

Comment: Is there something wrong with it that would prevent them from recognizing the `timer.entry1` doesn't exist?  `timer.entry1` should give hours the number of `hours`. then the loop will start and see that its been provided. I did something similar with my calculator but maybe im expecting too much by believing it should work similarly

Comment: Also, `hr` is being set to whatever `counter` / 3600 equals. thats how I get how many 'hours' is left. I know the while loop works because I have tested it outside of making the UI. The problem is that whenever I put whats in `timerstart` into `timerstart`, the thing breaks because it cant grab variables that aren't in the function. Or at least, I do not know how to. - If I have said something incorrect, please point it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
global hours
global minutes
global secs
global loop
global counter
```

This is incorrect, and does nothing. `global` is only supposed to be used inside functions, to tell the interpreter to look up the name you're assigning to in the global scope. To actually define a global variable, simply set it to an initial value.

```
hours = 0
minutes = 0
secs = 0
loop = 0
counter = 0
```

As an aside, you can use commas in `global` statements instead of putting one on each line. I'd also be worried about that infinite loop blocking your UI, but that's another issue.

Comment: Thanks for your help. You got the errors to stop but concerning your aside statement, the UI came up but now I got a problem with the loop not receiving the entries. I guess that's a problem for another question.

Comment: @user3763447 I think Tkinter may actually automatically handle putting the UI on a different thread, so in this case you should be fine. Just keep in mind for future programs that there are more Tkinter-integrated ways to approach this than an infinite loop.

Comment: I will keep it in mind. I have since not been able to figure out how to get the rest of the script to run. So I might open a new question.

Answer (score 1):

The variables `hours`, `minutes` and `secs` are only ever assigned by your `timerstart` function. However, that function is not called until after other code tries to access the values under those names. That's why you're getting errors.

To make things work correctly, you need to reorganize your code. A first step would be to give the variables I named above initial values. Your `global` statements at the top of the file don't do anything (`global` is only useful within a function, though it's not forbidden to put it elsewhere). Replace those statements with assignments like `hours = 0` instead, and you'll find that you get fewer `NameError`s.

I suspect you still have other issues though. Your `while` loop and the call to `timer.mainloop` both conflict with each other. They both want run indefinitely, but only one can be running at any given time. As it currently stands, your timer will completely tick down before the `tkinter` window has even been created!

You probably should find the appropriate mechanism to have a callback made on a timer from the `tkinter` code that will decrement your counter. You'll also need to update the logic that displays the remaining time, as the current code won't update itself as the numbers change. I don't know `tkinter` very well, so I'll leave it to you (and perhaps other answers) to find what the best solution is.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The person above you received the correct answer because I actually read his first and it worked. But thanks for addressing the second issue I encountered when the UI came up. It correctly showed but it didn't work as planned. So I you're correct when you mention that I need to find another way of making the timer work.